# Выдает ошибку TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from math import radians

Initial_value = pd.DataFrame({'X': [5, 4.3],
                                'Y': [-5.6, -1.2],
                          'Z': [0, 0],
                          'Theta': [0,0],
                          'Fi': [0,0],
                                'Psi': 
                  [np.radians(0),np.radians(90)]})

Initial_array = Initial_value.values
Initial_value.head()

def rotate(In_val): 
    P=[]


    P[0, 0] = cos(In_val['Fi'].values)*cos(In_val['Theta'].values)*cos(In_val['Psi'].values)-sin(In_val['Fi'].values)*sin(In_val['Psi'].values)
    P[0, 1] = -cos(In_val['Fi'].values)*cos(In_val['Theta'].values)*sin(In_val['Psi'].values)-sin(In_val['Fi'].values)*cos(In_val['Psi'].values)
    P[0, 2] = cos(In_val['Fi'].values)*sin(In_val['Theta'].values)
    P[0, 3] = In_val['X'].values
    P[1, 0] = sin(In_val['Fi'].values)*cos(In_val['Theta'].values)*cos(In_val['Psi'].values)+cos(In_val['Fi'].values)*sin(In_val['Psi'].values)
    P[1, 1] = -sin(In_val['Fi'].values)*cos(In_val['Theta'].values)*sin(In_val['Psi'].values)+cos(In_val['Fi'].values)*cos(In_val['Psi'].values)
    P[1, 2] = sin(In_val['Fi'].values)*sin(In_val['Theta'].values)
    P[1, 3] = In_val['Y'].values
    P[2, 0] = -sin(In_val['Theta'].values)*cos(In_val['Psi'].values)
    P[2, 1] = sin(In_val['Theta'].values)*sin(In_val['Psi'].values)
    P[2, 2] = cos(In_val['Theta'].values)
    P[2, 3] = In_val['Z'].values
    P[3, 0] = 0
    P[3, 1] = 0
    P[3, 2] = 0
    P[3, 3] = 1

    return P  
rotate(Initial_value)
```

Выдает ошибку. Как ее можно исправить?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNO7R.png

Comment: А в чём состоит ваш вопрос? "help please" - не  на русском и является просьбой, а не вопросом.

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802577/rotation-of-3d-vector)

Comment: А вообще на русскоязычном SO принято задавать вопросы на русском. И как вам уже сказали, сам вопрос вы забыли задать...